# phone to phone communicating in an android app?

Tags: android

If I wanted to make an app like snapchat, that just sends something quick to a users phone using the same app, what would I do to have them connect to each other? I have a basic idea on building apps but not the part where they can send and receive notifications to people in the apps addressbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snapchat doesn't work by sending the image directly to the other phone. There are servers and databases involved.

I suggest learning a backend language like **PHP** and a database language like **MYSQL** to get started!

But if you do want to learn phone to phone communication you can look up Bluetooth or NFC 
or even using sockets <-(Must be on the same network though to send info)

Comment: ok so if I understand what you are saying i would have to use a server and a database to make it work. In easier example of what i wanted to do would be use something like the facebook poke only for a phone. so you could just hit the poke button on your phone and it tells the other person they were poked so no picture sending just the two apps communicating.

Comment: @user2869238 You still need a server/database with some type of login or phone id to associate with the user/phone. Like snapchat, you have to login, thats how it knows who to send it too. Or else how else would your phone know where to send the "poke" too.

Comment: where would be a good place to start learning how to get the server/databse side done?

Comment: @user2869238 Android Hive is always a good place. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

You can send datas(text etc.) up to 4KB with Google GCM:
http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/gcm.html